# A function-definition is not allowed here before '{'

Tags: c++, sdl

i am getting a REALLY annoying error.  i literally looked everywhere for it!  i even went back and changed all of my

```
if (case)
    // to-do
```

to

```
if (case)
{
    // to-do
}
```

i don't ask a lot of questions like this, but i am really getting frustrated, and i am almost positive it is something simple that i am not seeing.

here is the error:

```
entity.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Entity::clean()’:
entity.cpp:148: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
entity.cpp:394: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
```

here is my class code:

```
#include "./entity.hpp"

std::vector<Entity *> Entity::entity_list_;
std::vector<EntityCollision> EntityCollision::collision_list_;

EntityCollision::EntityCollision()
{
  a_ = NULL;
  b_ = NULL;
}

Entity::Entity()
{
  image_buffer_ = NULL;
  x_ = y_ = 0.0f;
  width_ = height_ = 0;
  animation_state_ = 0;
  move_left_ = false;
  move_right_ = false;
  type_ = ENTITY_TYPE_GENERIC;
  flags_ = ENTITY_FLAG_GRAVITY;
  dead_ = false;
  speed_x_ = 0;
  speed_y_ = 0;
  max_speed_x_ = 0;
  max_speed_y_ = 0;
  column_x_ = 0;
  column_y_ = 0;
  column_width_ = 0;
  column_height_ = 0;
}

Entity::~Entity()
{
}

bool Entity::init(const std::string &image_file, int width, int height, int max_frames)
{
  if ((image_buffer_ = Surface::mount_image(image_file)) == NULL)
    {
      return false;
    }

  animation_helper_.max_frames_ = max_frames;

  width_ = width;
  height_ = height;
  return Surface::set_color_key(255, 0, 255, image_buffer_);
}

void Entity::render(SDL_Surface *dest)
{
  if (image_buffer_ == NULL || dest == NULL)
    {
      return;
    }

  Surface::draw(x_ - CameraManager::camera_controller_.x(),
        y_ - CameraManager::camera_controller_.y(),
        current_frame_column_ * width_,
        (current_frame_row_ + animation_helper_.current_frame()) * height_,
        width_, height_,
        image_buffer_,
        dest);
}

void Entity::animate()
{
  if (move_left_)
    {
      current_frame_column_ = 0;
    }
  else if (move_right_)
    {
      current_frame_column_ = 1;
    }

  animation_helper_.animate();
}

void Entity::collision(Entity *entity)
{
}

void Entity::update()
{
  /* if the entity isn't moving left or right */
  if (move_left_ == false && move_right_ == false)
    {
      stop(); // stop movement
    }

  if (move_left_) // if it wants to move left
    {
      accel_x_ = -0.5; // move negatively down x axis
    }
  else if (move_right_)
    {
      accel_x_ = 0.5; // move positively up the x axis
    }

  /* if gravity is applied to the entity */
  if (flags_ & ENTITY_FLAG_GRAVITY)
    {
      accel_y_ = 0.75f; // it will fall
    }

  /* set the entity's speed */
  speed_x_ += accel_x_ * FPSManager::fps_controller_.speed_factor();
  speed_y_ += accel_y_ * FPSManager::fps_controller_.speed_factor();

  /* make sure the entity won't move too fast */
  if (speed_x_ > max_speed_x_)
    {
      speed_x_ = max_speed_x_;
    }

  if (speed_x_ < -max_speed_x_)
    {
      speed_x_ = -max_speed_x_;
    }

  if (speed_y_ > max_speed_y_)
    {
      speed_y_ = max_speed_y_;
    }

  if (speed_y_ < -max_speed_y_)
    {
      speed_y_ = -max_speed_y_;
    }

  animate(); // animate the entity
  move(speed_x_, speed_y_); // now move it
}

void Entity::clean()
{
  if (image_buffer_) // if the image buffer has an image on it
    {
      SDL_FreeSurface(image_buffer_); // get rid of it!
    }

  image_buffer_ = NULL; // just set it to null if it doesn't :\
}

void Entity::move(float x, float y)
{
  /* if thee entity  doesn't want to move, why try? */
  if (x == 0 && y == 0)
    {
      return;
    }

  double new_x = 0; // the x position increment
  double new_y = 0; // the y position increment

  /* give us the correct movement per second */
  x *= FPSManager::fps_controller_.speed_factor();
  y *= FPSManager::fps_controller_.speed_factor();

  if (y != 0) // if we should move up or down
    {
      if (y >= 0) // down in this case
      {
        new_y = FPSManager::fps_controller_.speed_factor();
      }
        else // up in this case
      {
        new_y = -FPSManager::fps_controller_.speed_factor();
      }
    }

  while (true)
    {
      if (flags_ & ENTITY_FLAG_GHOST) // is the entity a ghost?
      {
        /* notify the entity of other collisions */
        valid_pos((int) (x_ + new_x), (int) (y_ + new_y));
        /* move regardless of the results */
        x_ += new_x_;
        y_ += new_y_;
      }
      else
      {
        /* if the new y position is valid (empty) */
        if (valid_pos((int) (x_ + new_x), (int) y_))
          {
            x_ += new_x; // move the entity
          }
        else
          {
            speed_x_ = 0;
          }

      /* if the new y position is valid (empty) */
      if (valid_pos((int) x_, (int) (y_ + new_y)))
        {
          y_ += new_y; // move the entity
        }
      else
        {
          speed_y_ = 0;
        }
    }

      /* decrease x by new_x until it reaches 0 */
      x += -new_x;

      /* decrease y by new_y until it reaches 0 */
      y += -new_y;

      if (new_x > 0 && x <= 0)
      {
        new_x = 0;
      }

      if (new_x < 0 && x >= 0)
      {
        new_x = 0;
      }

      if (new_y > 0 && y <= 0)
      {
        new_y = 0;
      }

      if (new_y < 0 && y >= 0)
      {
        new_y = 0;
      }

      /* if the entity reached it's new position on the x axis */
      if (x == 0)
      {
        new_x = 0; // don't move left || right anymore
      }

      /* if the entity reached it's new position on the y axis */
      if (y == 0)
      {
        new_y = 0; // don't move up || down anymore
      }

      /* when we finally come to a stop */
      if (x == 0 && y == 0)
      {
        break; // break out of the loop
      }

      if (new_x == 0 && new_y == 0)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
}

void Entity::stop()
{
  if (speed_x_ > 0)
    {
      accel_x_ = -1;
    }

  if (speed_x_ < 0)
    {
      accel_x_ = 1;
    }

  if (speed_x_ < 2.0f && speed_x_ > -2.0f)
    {
      accel_x_ = 0;
      speed_x_ = 0;
    }
}

bool Entity::collides(int o_x, int o_y, int o_w, int o_h)
{
  int left1, left2;
  int right1, right2;
  int top1, int top2;
  int bottom1, int bottom2;

  int t_x = (int) x_ + column_x_;
  int t_y = (int) y_ + column_y_;

  left1 = t_x;
  left2 = o_x;

  right1 = left1 + width_ - 1 - column_width_;
  right2 = o_x + o_w - 1;

  top1 = t_y;
  top2 = o_y;

  bottom1 = top1 + height_ - 1 - column_height_;
  bottom2 = o_y + o_h - 1;

  if (bottom1 < top2)
    {
      return false;
    }

  if (top1 > bottom2)
    {
      return false;
    }

  if (right1 < left2)
    {
      return false;
    }

  if (left1 > right2)
    {
      return false;
    }

  return true;
}

bool valid_pos(int x, int y)
{
  bool _return = true;

  int start_x = (x + column_x_) / TILE_SIZE;
  int start_y = (y + column_y_) / TILE_SIZE;

  int end_x = ((x + column_x_) + width_ - column_width_ - 1) / TILE_SIZE;
  int end_y = ((x + column_y_) + height_ - column_height_ - 1) / TILE_SIZE;

  for (int i_y = start_y; i_y < end_y; i_y++)
    {
      for (int i_x = start_x; i_x < end_x; i_x++)
      {
        Tile *tile = MapManager::map_control_.get_tile(i_x * TILE_SIZE,
                             i_y * TILE_SIZE);
        if (valid_pos_tile(tile) == false)
          {
            _return = false;
          }
      }
    }

  if (flags_ & ENTITY_FLAG_MAPONLY)
    {
    }
  else
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < entity_list_.size(); i++)
      {
        if (!valid_pos_entity(entity_list_[i], x, y))
          {
            _return = false;
          }
      }
    }

  return _return;
}

bool valid_pos(Tile *t)
{
  if (t == NULL)
    {
      return true;
    }

  if (tile->type_id_ == TILE_TYPE_BLOCK)
    {
      return false;
    }

  return true;
}

bool valid_pos(Entity *e, int x, int y)
{
  if ((this != e) && (e != NULL) && (e->dead_ == false) &&
      (e->flags_ ^ ENTITY_FLAG_MAPONLY) &&
      (e->collides(x + column_x, y + column_y,
          width_ - column_width_ - 1,
           height_ - column_height_ - 1) == true))
    {
      EntityCollision ec;
      ec.a_ = this;
      ec.b_ = e;

      EntityCollision::collision_list_.push_back(ec);
      return false;
    }

  return true;
}
```

thanks

edit: i don't know why some of the indentation broke.  fixing it now.

Comment: It might help if you show us the lines where the errors are happening.

Comment: For future reference only post the minimal example exhibiting your error, not your whole code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
  image_buffer_ = NULL; // just set it to null if it doesn't :\
}
```

Placing a backslash at the end of a line splices it with the line that follows, which, effectively, comments out the closing bracket in your function.

Comment: ohh so my smiley was the problem!!! D-:<  thanks!  now i have a lot more but i can fix those.

Comment: @evolon696, not _all_ smileys, just the ones where you're confused :-)

Answer (score 6):

Watch this line:

```
  image_buffer_ = NULL; // just set it to null if it doesn't :\
```

This begins a multi-line comment, commenting out the following:

```
}
```

Your compiler should warn you about this.

Remove the `\` and then you can move on to the rest of your warnings and errors!

Answer (score 3):

```
    image_buffer_ = NULL; // just set it to null if it doesn't :\
}
```

Here's a hint: what do you think the escape character `\` does to the newline at the end of that line?

Yes, that's right, it escapes it, effectively bringing the closing brace on the next line into the comment.

Hence, you're missing a closing brace.

Maybe you should keep your emotions out of the code :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use an auto-indenting code editor (and if you don't, why not?), it would immediately show you where the unbalanced braces are. (Assuming, of course, that it's smart enough to recognize the // ...\ as a multi-line comment :-)

Comment: Checked — VIM 7.3 is not smart enough.