# Bug through a single-line comment before a line with a statement

Tags: c++, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859491/a-function-definition-is-not-allowed-here-before)

I would like to share this bug I did in my code, one of the hard to find ones:

```
#include <iostream>

void StartNuclearWar() {
    std::cout << "War in progress..." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;

    // Get activation codes from C:\codes\
    a = 1;

    if(a == 0) {
        StartNuclearWar();
    }
}
```

Where is it?

Comment: I want to see a nuclear war!

Comment: Heh. I thought only the preprocessor treated back-slashes that way

Comment: @Ancurio It's the preprocessor that handles comments (as in, purges them from the stream).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes how did I not know this all those past years....

Comment: FWIW, unlike Prettify, vim syntax highlighting makes this obvious.

Comment: Closers: please explain. Self-answered questions are perfectly valid here.

Comment: @JanDvorak: see the revision history of the question.

Comment: @Fanael not everyone was closing the old version. Even then, the proper response is what H2CO3 did IMO.

Comment: Because a blog post isn't a question? I'd also close a post that said "Look, here's how you write a `for` loop without curly braces"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bug is in the comment: for us the final \ character represents a directory, for the compiler it means that the following line is part of the current line.
Of course every developer knows that, but in this case this detail is quite well hidden.

Comment: Now it's better organized. +1.

Comment: Not even Prettify (the engine here) can handle that correctly

Comment: Paying attention to compiler warning can significantly help in searching such bugs. `MSVC`  generates warning by default, `gcc`, when `-Wcomment` (`-Wall`) is provided.

Answer (score 2):

Nice gotcha, MSDN calls this [line splicing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxss3ska.aspx).

> All lines ending in a backslash (`\`) and immediately followed by a newline character are joined with the next line in the source file forming logical lines from the physical lines. Unless it is empty, a source file must end in a newline character that is not preceded by a backslash.

Comment: Sorry, minor edit to make the backslash visible, because your quote didn't make sense as was.